# Restore PostGreSQL materialized views

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I'm unfortunately getting stuck on database stuff with PostGreSQL..

I created some materialized views in two schemas "schema1" and "schema2".  These materialized views work well.
Then I made a backup of my database with PgAdmin.
And finally, I restored that database in an other server.

But this does not work as expected : all the materialized views have not been created (whereas both tables and classic views of "schema1" and "schema2" did)...
Hence my question : is it possible to restore materialized views. And if yes, can PgAdmin do the trick ?

Thanks you !

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense that PG won't include the calculated materialized view in the backup since they can be generated from the data in the tables.

This is explained in more detail on the answer to this [question from the Database Admin SO](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93184/is-it-possible-to-backup-and-restore-a-materialized-view-with-its-data)

To get the materialized view populated again after the backup you could try  [refreshing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) it.

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW mymatview;
```

If you need to keep the data as it was at the time each backup, then perhaps you could insert select it into a table before the backup operation.

Comment: Thanks for both answer and link. But that would make sense if no views had been created.. and the thing is that all my classic views are created in "schema1" and "schema2" What's more when I tried to restore materialized views located in the public schema it worked.. whereas I have 0 materialized view in my two other schemas "schema1" and "schema2"..